Abbott 2.3.9: what can we say about this sequence?
I am struggling with exercise 2.3.9 in Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis.
The question is: Let $(a_n)$ be bounded by $M$, but not necessarily convergent, and suppose $(b_n)$ converges to $b$ where $b \neq 0$. Can we conclude anything about the convergence of $(a_nb_n)$?
My first thought was to note that if $(a_n)$ was constant then we could prove $(a_nb_n)$ converges to $a_nb$ with the algebraic limit theorem, then argue that, since we don't actually know enough about $(a_n)$ to say it is constant, we can't say whether or not $(a_nb_n)$ converges. But I realized that this does not follow - perhaps it is the case that this one sufficient condition for the convergence of $(a_nb_n)$ cannot be proven true or false but also that there are other sufficient conditions that can be proven true. I then set out to either find one such condition or to rule them out generally, but I could do neither, and now I am out of ideas.

$(a_nb_n)$ converges if and only if $(a_n)$ converges.

There is no convergence, for example $b_n=1$, $a_n = (-1)^n$. 
But $a_n$ is bounded, therefore there is a convergent subsequence $a_{n_k} \to a$ hence a  convergent subsequence $a_{n_k}b_{n_k} \to ab$.

While correct I would say this answer is not technically “allowed” for this problem because it looks like you’re assuming “every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence” which has not been established at this point in this book.
